# Inject a angluarjs directive element with innerHTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, innerhtml

I'm looking for help for the following problem :

I have a **directive** call "hello" :

```
.directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/dashboard/templates/hello.html'
    }
});
```

Here is the **template** (really simple it's for a test) :

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

And I have a controller where i'm trying to inject this directive :

```
(...)
cell = document.getElementById("body");
cell.innerHTML = "<hello></hello>";
(...)
```

**My problem :**
The "hello" element is correctly insert in the html page but the "hello word" message in the template is not displayed

If I directly put the element  in the html page it works...

Could you please help me to understand the problem and find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: This is not how you do this in angular.  You should not be using cell = document.getElementById("body");
cell.innerHTML = "<hello></hello>";.  You do in fact put the element directly on the page like you said above.

Comment: thank you for this answer, but my problem is that this element is not systematically insert : it depend, sometimes I insert an other element, actually I have more than 20 possibilities.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: You still do not change the DOM from the controller.  You can use ng-if or ng-hide.

Comment: yes, I know ng-if and ng-switch, but I tried to simplify by handle this in the directive. But you're wright I will manage to handle this in html with ng-if or ng-switch. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uR6ViwNaaVZijSElrTJz?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}).directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'hello.html'
    }
});


  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <hello></hello>
  </body>
```